# Combos on close SPX

Tags: options

I am wondering if anyone has any information on how combos on close trade. I've been looking at the BTIC (http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/equity-index/btic-block-trades.html) and was wondering if there was anyway to get something similar on SPX options to actually trade the closing price of the SPX + some offset for forward alignment without doing a jellyroll.

Thanks!
Andrew

Answer (score 1):

There are "Combo-On-Close" for SPX options but they are OTC.  Can you trade OTC?  The main IDBs set markets in those.  Obviously you would have to hedge your cash somehow.

Comment: Can you give me some info on how wide those generally are and what are the quoting conventions? The main IDBs I'm assuming are the ICAP, PREBON, TFS etc.

Comment: Sure, very similar to the EFP.  From FGC just now they gave me -6.3/5-9. That's about the same now as the EFP and the electronic market implied from cash to futures is about -6.05x-6.27

Comment: So basically much wider than floors. Floors are generally about a nickel wide and you have the btic as well

Comment: Yeah, but they tighten up sometimes a lot.  They are popular with derrivs desks.  You will often see them quoted when they need to hedge their gamma at the end of the day.

Answer (score 0):

Someone asked me similar question last week. No combos never trade at close in spx. Most people trade weekly to Jun {front  fut}or  various weekly rolls in spx . I looked at btic once, it was trading almost same level as roll mkt. If you traded combo you would hedge with future anyway? Btic seems like cool product to trade efp market. I am not sure if this answers you question but if you have more questions about spx rolls let me know.
John